# Does filtering using manual metrics in Sonar still (or again) not work?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I am using Sonar 4.5.5, and I tried to use manual metrics in filters. No luck, also not with the ones provided by default. I searched the archives and Stackoverflow and Jira for that, nothing. Any insights?

Edit: The same behavior applies to version 5.1.2, justed tried that out today.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I found out why Sonar behaves like this!

After creating a measurement, it takes another analysis run to activate the measurements. The 'Manual Measures' dialog of any project tells me that in bold letters: "**Pending measures are marked with orange box. Their values will be integrated to project during next analysis.**". Maybe my question and answer helps others to be faster with this.